# What does casting to int8_t* even mean in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>

using std::cout;

int main() {
    // 281474976710656 is 0x0001000000000000
    int64_t arr[] = {281474976710656, LONG_MAX};
    int64_t nal = (int64_t)arr + 1;

    int64_t deref = *(int8_t *)nal;
    int64_t deref_as_64p = *(int64_t *)nal;

    std::stringstream derefs, deref_as_64ps;
    derefs << std::hex << deref;
    deref_as_64ps << std::hex << deref_as_64p;

    cout << std::hex << derefs.str() << "\n";
    cout << std::hex << deref_as_64ps.str() << "\n";
}
```

The output in my machine is:

```
0
ff00010000000000
```

What I expect is:

- **1** Because if `arr` is the pointer to some byte `B` then `nal` should be the pointer to `B + 1`. When I convert it to `int8_t`, I expect to get the next 8 bits starting from `B + 1`.
- **1000000000000FF** 64 bits from `B + 1`.

Where do numbers I got came from?

**Clarification:**
I am aware of undefined behavior in integer to pointer conversion and unaligned access.

My architecture is `x86`, more specifically:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
```

My kernel is:

```
5.5.5-arch1-1
```

I am interested in all the explanations that include platform-specific details.

Comment: Casting between integers and pointers has implementation-defined results.

Comment: I think you're getting those results because the byte order of your machine is not what you expect.

Comment: @Barmar: On top of that, `*(int64_t *)nal;` isn't guaranteed to work; it's accessing unaligned memory (because `nal` is one byte beyond the eight byte alignment of `arr`), which is fine (if sometimes slower) on some architectures, and can crash the program on others.

Comment: `int64_t nal = (int64_t)arr + 1; int64_t deref = *(int8_t *)nal;` also invokes UB because unaligned access isn't allowed everywhere. To convert between pointers and integers you must use `(u)intptr_t` instead of `int64_t`

Comment: @phuclv: Assuming `(u)intptr_t` is used, `*(int8_t *)nal` should be fine (if implementation defined due to byte order issues), right? It's one byte access to one byte aligned memory. It's the `*(int64_t *)nal` that causes problems, because it's eight byte access to memory that's not even two byte aligned.

Comment: Your example does leave room for uncertainty. Could you try an experiment where you initialize `arr[0]` to `0x0102030405060708` instead of `281474976710656`?

Comment: `*(int64_t *)nal` causes undefined behaviour so the entire program output is not covered by the standard

Comment: @phuclv `intptr_t` is just a typedef for another integer type, probably the same one as `int64_t`; that change would make no substantial difference if OP is on a normal 64-bit system. (and if we're concerned about portability, using `int8_t *` instead of an integer type would make more sense)

Comment: @M.M you're right. I have updated the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though the behavior you see is, as others have said, undefined by the C++ standard, it seems not terribly helpful to stop there. What you see is exactly what you should expect from a straightforward translation of your source code into machine code by a reasonable compiler for a little-endian architecture on a system with a 64-bit or smaller address space that permits unaligned accesses and whose 'long' type is 32 bits. An optimizing compiler ***might*** do strange things since it detects that you're doing something with undefined behavior, but with optimizations off, or when using what I'd call a ***reasonable*** compiler even with high optimization, the results you see are exactly what you'd expect on such a system.

Your main point of confusion is probably related to the endianness. Your `arr[]` array is probably not stored in memory byte-for-byte like you expect. Here, I've defined arrays with the same byte layout in two different ways:

```
// 281474976710656 is 0x0001000000000000  
int64_t arr[] = { 0x0001000000000000, 0x000000007fffffff }; //  { 281474976710656, LONG_MAX };
// ...on a little endian machine (like x86), the bytes of that array are stored like this:
int8_t arr8[] = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00,
                  0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
```

In little-endian format (a very common format), the hardware interprets the lowest-address byte as the lowest-order (least significant) byte, and the highest-address byte as the highest-order (most significant) byte. Though it's more confusing when looking at a memory dump, there is a small potential performance advantage to this order: When you cast a multibyte scalar value from a wider width to a smaller width (e.g. from `int64_t` to `int32_t`), on a little-endian system, the address in memory of the smaller object is the same address as the larger (uncast) object. In a big-endian system, the addresses **are** necessarily different. On the little-endian system, if the compiler wishes to optimize a read access of a scalar value that will be cast to a smaller type, it can just emit an instruction to read the smaller type in the first place from the same address that it would have read the larger type. In a big-endian system, the compiler would have to issue an additional instruction to adjust the address before reading it (or issue a larger instruction that adjusts the address as it reads it). (Or, read the entire larger object & then mask off the top portion; any way you look at it, on a big-endian system, it can't be more efficient than that same operation on an otherwise identical little-endian system.)

***Anyway, back to your code...***

When your code casts `arr` to an `int64_t` and adds 1 to it, what you get is the address of the **bold** byte:

> int8_t arr8[] = { 0x00, **0x00**, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

So when when you cast that as an `(int8_t *)` and dereference it, you're reading the single byte at that address and getting `0x00`.

When your code then casts the same `nal` pointer as `(int64_t *)`, because that unaligned access is permitted ***on your system***, what you get is the 8 **bold** bytes below...

> int8_t arr8[] = { 0x00, **0x00**, **0x00**, **0x00**, **0x00**, **0x00**, **0x01**, **0x00**, **0xff**, 0xff, 0xff, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

...but the hardware reads it in little-endian format. That's why you're getting `ff0001000000000000` instead of `100ff`...

...which is another point: I'm not sure why you were expecting `1000000000000FF`; I don't think that's a reasonable expectation on any system (undefined behavior notwithstanding). On a big-endian system, your `arr[]` array's byte layout would be like this:

```
int8_t arr8[] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
```

And if you cast `nal` as an `(int64_t)` on a big-endian system (all other traits being the same, including permitting unaligned accesses), you'd get the **bold** bytes below...

> int8_t arr8[] = { 0x00, **0x01**, **0x00**, **0x00**, **0x00**, **0x00**, **0x00**, **0x00**, **0x00**, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };

...read by the hardware in big-endian format, giving you the resulting string `100000000000000`.

Comment: Thank you. This explains it.